# How can I call an instance of a Class inside another Class in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop, instance

I am just learning Python, and I have to make a game project using, ideally, OOP paradigm. Sorry if the question is too basic or poorly explained. I am just taking my first steps.

First, create a Player class and then an Enemies class. One method of the Player class is to fight with an instance of the Enemies class.

```
import random
import time

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = 10
        self.atk = 2
        self.dodge = 50

    def fight(self, enemy):
        enemy.show_stats()
        while True:
            print("Player's turn.")
            time.sleep(1)
            enemy_dodge_calc = random.randrange(0,101)
            if enemy_dodge_calc >= enemy.dodge:
                enemy.hp -= self.atk
                print(f"You hit the enemy with {self.atk} points!")
                if enemy.hp > 0:
                    print(f"Remaining enemy's HP: {enemy.hp} points\n")
                    time.sleep(1)
                else:
                    print(f"Remaining enemy's HP: 0 points")
                    print("You defeated the enemy\n")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    break
            else:
                print("The enemy dodges your hit!\n")
                time.sleep(1)

            print("Enemy's turn.")
            time.sleep(1)
            player_dodge_calc = random.randrange(0,101)
            if player_dodge_calc >= self.dodge:
                self.hp -= enemy.atk
                print(f"The enemy hits you with {enemy.atk} points!")
                if self.hp > 0:
                    print(f"Remaining player's HP: {self.hp} points\n")
                    time.sleep(1)
                else:
                    print(f"Remaining player's HP: 0 points")
                    print("Game Over! =(")
                    time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print("You dodge the enemy's hit!\n")
                time.sleep(1)

class Enemies:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hp = random.randrange(4,7)
        self.atk = random.randrange(1,4)
        self.dodge = random.randrange(20,41)

    def show_stats(self):
        print(f"Enemy HP: {self.hp}")
        print(f"Enemy ATK: {self.atk}")
        print(f"Enemy Probability of dodge: {self.dodge}%\n")
        time.sleep(2)

player = Player("Aliersh")
enemy = Enemies()
player.fight(enemy)
```

The code works, but it is still not clear to me how to call the Enemies class inside the Fight method of the Player class.

I added the parameter enemy inside the fight method following a code of the class I'm in, but I don't understand how python makes the method point directly to the other class, if, according to me, at any time I don't do it inside the code.

That goes to the more general question, how do I make instances of each class interact?

Comment: Call it in what way? You passed the `enemy` instance as a parameter, and you're accessing the attributes with code like `enemy.atk`.

Comment: If you want more interaction, you should define methods in the `Enemies` class. You can then use `enemy.methodname()` to call the method.